# JavaScript - Format Multiple Variable Output in One Line

Tags: javascript, output

I've searched as much as I can but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to write a simple JS command that will output a formatted string that contains 3 variables that are evenly spaced.

For example, when I did this in C++ I used `setw`

Sample output would be like this:

```
var1 = "First"
var2 = "Second"
var3 = "Third"

[VARIABLE 1][VARIABLE 2][VARIABLE 3]
    First      Second      Third
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no straight equivalent for this in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes there is really.

Comment: What is the context here? Are you just trying to log a string? Or are you looking to format the output in a webpage?

If it's the latter, this can/should probably be better handled by the presentation layer using HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.prototype.padEnd()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) and [String.prototype.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and length of string to do that.

Code below:

```
var1 = "First";
var2 = "Second";
var3 = "Third";

//skip 3 whitespace each string
console.log(
   var1.padStart(3+var1.length)
   +var2.padStart(3+var2.length)
   +var3.padStart(3+var3.length));
```

Hope it makes your day.